# What causes portions of drywall mud/patch plaster to become discolored and harder?

Tags: drywall, plaster, water-damage

I was having water issues on the wall above my fireplace, after gutters/tuck pointing/some roofing being fixed the water has stopped.

I went to patch some of the areas that had the worst water damage. Scraped off the affected areas, let everything sit for a week in-case there was additional water, applied patch plaster.

I am having places where when the plaster dries it is a different color than the surrounding plaster and it is MUCH harder. So hard it is almost unsandable completely where the rest of the plaster seems to be about as hard to sand as any other hot mud I've dealt with.

Am I doing something wrong or is there something leeching out of the wall into the plaster that I need to be worried about?

[image: Picture of area with patch plaster]

Comment: What brand/type mud did you use... that looks like Durabond.

Comment: DAP Plaster Wall Patch (Dry Mix)